# Use Parameters in Table in Search Query in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a saved table dataset in Splunk. When I choose to "Investigate in Search" this table dataset, I see

**sample 1**

```
| from datamodel:"My_Table_ForDay"
```

The SPL `My_Table_ForDay` looks like the following:

**sample 2**

```
index="my_index"
sourcetype="*"
earliest=@d
latest=now
| fields
  _time
  statusCode
  result
| table
  _time
  statusCode
  result
```

I would like to reuse `My_Table_ForDay` for separate days. In other words, I would like to pass a value to the datamodel that's used in the query. I want to use a parameter for the `earliest` attribute. For example, I would pass the following parameter values:

- For today: `@d`
- For yesterday: `-1d@d`
- Two days ago: `-2d@d`

How do I a) pass a value from sample 1 and b) use a parameter in sample 2?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `from` command does not support passing arguments.  The `savedsearch` command does, however.  You could save Sample2 as this saved search

```
index="my_index"
sourcetype="*"
earliest=$earliest_time$
latest=now
| fields
  _time
  statusCode
  result
| table
  _time
  statusCode
  result
```

And then invoke it using `| savedsearch My_Table_ForDay earliest_time="@d".  See https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.2.6/SearchReference/Savedsearch for details.